# Trying to add ScrollPane in Jpanel with null layout inside BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, null, scrollpane

I am trying to add a scrollbar in jpanel with null layout.

I want to create a form. This should should display few buttons at the bottom at all times.Any content inside form should maintain it's size and ratio even if the parent container is resized.

Here is what I've come with. I have a panel with borderlayout and added buttons at the south of border. Then created another jpanel to contain form that is added at the center of parent jpanel. Since I want form to maintain it's ratio I went with null layout for inner panel. But I want it to display scrollbar when content is not fully visible. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aahRM.png)

Now adding inner jpanel into scrollpane and adding scrollpanel into parent panel (.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER)) doesn't give desired format.
Is there any thing that I can do to get desired format?

Here is code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
    Container c = jFrame.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    bottomPanel(c);
    centerPanel(c); //scrollbar should go in this panel
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void centerPanel(Container c) {
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(null);
    JButton button = new JButton("This jObject should not resize when window resizes and also should maintain relative position.");
    button.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 10, 600, 50));
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Just like it works in this code. Just Add ScrollPane to centerPanel That is in green backround");
    button1.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 70, 600, 50));
    JButton button2 = new JButton("For clearity");
    button2.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 130, 600, 50));
    centerPanel.add(button);
    centerPanel.add(button1);
    centerPanel.add(button2);
    centerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    c.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private static void bottomPanel(Container c) {
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(); //Buttons that goes at the bottom of screen will go in here
    JPanel bottomInnerPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomInnerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    bottomInnerPanel.add(new JButton("Add"), BorderLayout.WEST);
    bottomInnerPanel.add(new JButton("Search"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    bottomPanel.add(bottomInnerPanel);
    bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    c.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: Could you add your current code to your question ?

Comment: Try to learn `LayoutManager`s. The concept is perfect (IMHO) but the build-in `GridBagLayout` is ugly. So I would suggest you to learn one of third-party managers, for example [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: I need to be assured that it will fullfill what I want to do before I venture into new learning adventure. Especially when I am in tight time bound. BTW is it open source or atleast free to use cause I cannot pay for anything right now.

Comment: The problem is, that nobody will reinvent the wheel for you. Layout managers was made to solve the resizing problems. So either you try to learn `LayoutManager`s or you risk to get no answer for you question (especially without [mcve]). And yes, `MigLayout` is a freeware.

Comment: `Any content inside form should maintain it's size and ratio even if the parent container is resized` and `But I want it to display scrollbar when content is not fully visible` - well those are conflicting requirements. If you continuously scale the components then they will always fit inside the panel so there is no need for a scroll pane. I would suggest only certain components on the panel need to resize. You could look at the [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#gridbag) as it allows you to specify resizing constraints.

Comment: You can also nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout. Without details we can't offer specific advice, other than don't use a null layout.

Comment: Sorry that my description was too vague. Think of it like something like text editor. Whenever we resize text editor font of text don't changes. Only a scroll bar appears when the window is too small. Here instead of text I have jObjects. PS: My layout is not finalized so feel free if there is other better ways.